# Example of compact $CD(K,\infty)$ space, but doubling condition fails

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

It's well known that the doubling condition may not hold on $CD(K,\infty)$ space. 
Can one give an example such that: $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space, $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure and $(X,d,\mu)$ is a $CD(K,\infty)$ space, but the doubling condition fails?

Comment: Hilbert cube. (too short for an answer)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:What's the probability measure $\mu$? Why does this space satisfy $CD(K,\infty)$?

Comment: Take the product measure, $CD(0,\infty)$ can be checked directly, or you may think of it as a limit space of n-dimensional rectangles for $n\to\infty$.